# Push notifications for Microsoft authenticator app gets permanently disabled after reset of iOS settings

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, microsoft

I’m having the same issue in this post: [Push notifications for Microsoft authenticator app gets permanently disabled after reset of iOS settings](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/push-notifications-for-microsoft-authenticator-app/83ed14aa-36d7-43fb-b0d5-ea0d5091ba49)

The notification setting won’t even show up because the app will not request to send notifications again. The only solution in the thread is to reinstall the app. Is there an alternative to reinstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m actually documenting my solution for future reference since the MS thread is locked.

The solution is to hit the hamburger on the left and click on ‘Backup this device’. You may get a pop up to add a personal Microsoft account. Click on Ok.

You don’t actually have to add an account though. Just clicking on it will cause a notification permission request to pop up which you can grant.

This way you can reenable push notifications without having to reinstall the app

[image]

Comment: The "Backup this device" option isn't there for me anymore, so I just pressed the "+" to start to create a new account, selected a personal account, and then received the  allow notifications dialogue which resolved the issue. As rsn notes, I did not have to actually go through with the full account set up process.